# Variable "time" in jPlayer does not seem possible. Is there a way to pass a variable?

Tags: jquery, jplayer

I am trying to pass in a variable for "time" in jPlayer's play function, but it never seems to work.

The method looks like this:

$(id).jPlayer( "play", [Number: time] )

The example given in the documentation is like this:

```
$("#jpId").jPlayer("play", 42); // Begins playing 42 seconds into the media.
```

In my implementation, it looks like this:

```
    var seconds = '300';
    var mp3 = 'my_mp3_path';
    console.log("seconds is: "+seconds);

        $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
            ready: function(event) {
                $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                    mp3: mp3
                });
                $(this).jPlayer("play", seconds);
            },
            errorAlerts: true,
            swfPath: "/js",
            supplied: "mp3, oga",
            solution:"html,flash"
        });
```

The console shows "seconds is 300".

The mp3 variable works.

But for some reason, the time variable ("seconds") does not work at all! No matter what I enter, it always starts from zero (and does play the correct mp3). The "time" seems to be undefined, but I don't know how to define it. In all the documentation, the time variable is specified with a number, not a variable, so I'm not sure what I can change to make it work.. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried using the number `300` instead of the string `'300'`? And are you sure it's in seconds and not milliseconds? (Most javascript apis use milliseconds.)

Comment: Amazing! I spent so much time trying to figure it out, and you were right - just needed to be cast as an Integer first. I'm actually getting the number from somewhere else, so I just did parseInt(seconds) to get it right. It IS supposed to be full seconds in jPlayer, but the string issue was the problem. Thank you!

Comment: If you can add that as an answer, I can pick it so you get credit..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument to `jPlayer` should be a number, not a stringified number:

```
var seconds = 300;
```